# How to move the Quiz interface to the next question?

Tags: flutter

Here is the code for a Quiz App I have been making. This is the main.dart file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const Quizzler(),
  );
}

class Quizzler extends StatefulWidget {
  const Quizzler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Quizzler> createState() => _QuizzlerState();
}

class _QuizzlerState extends State<Quizzler> {
  List<Widget> scoreKeeper = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    Quiz().getQuestion(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            boolButton(Colors.green, 'True'),
            boolButton(Colors.red, 'False'),
            Row(
              children: scoreKeeper,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded boolButton(Color c, String s) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(c),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(
              () {
                switcher(s);
                Quiz().nextQuestion();
              },
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            s,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  switcher(String s) {
    if (Quiz().getAnswer().toLowerCase() == s.toLowerCase()) {
      scoreKeeper.add(
        const Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      scoreKeeper.add(
        const Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is the list.dart file that I imported onto the main.dart file:

```
import 'question.dart';

class Quiz {
  int _counter = 0;

  final List<Question> _q = [
    Question(
      'Cows can only be lead up a flight of stairs and not down.',
      'False',
    ),
    Question(
      'Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.',
      'True',
    ),
    Question(
      'A slug\'s blood is green.',
      'True',
    ),
  ];

  void nextQuestion() {
    _counter++;
  }

  String getQuestion() {
    return _q[_counter].question;
  }

  String getAnswer() {
    return _q[_counter].answer;
  }
}
```

And this is the question.dart file that I imported onto the list.dart file:

```
class Question {
  String question;
  String answer;
  Question(this.question, this.answer);
}
```

[image: Image of Quiz Interface]

In the Quiz app, once I hit True or False it just shows a tick for the right answer (False) and a cross for the wrong answer (True), without moving to the next question. How do I fix this?

Comment: `onPressed: () { setState(() {switcher(s);Quiz().nextQuestion();},);},` here, remove `Quiz().nextQuestion();`

Comment: @Tuan, that doesn't work; just tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you call any variables or methods from `Quiz` class by calling directly by `Quiz()`, basically problems occur here.

By calling `Quiz()` every time you created a new object, there is no tracking of this object. Because you don't save the object.

So, at first, save the object like that...

```
Quiz quiz = Quiz();
```

then wherever you call by `Quiz()`, replace by `quiz`.
be like..... `quiz.getQuestion()`,`quiz.nextQuestion()`,`quiz.getAnswer()`
I add all three dart file added below ... with the solution of showing a ques ending alert snackbar. 
This is the `main.dart` file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const Quizzler(),
  );
}

class Quizzler extends StatefulWidget {
  const Quizzler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Quizzler> createState() => _QuizzlerState();
}

class _QuizzlerState extends State<Quizzler> {

  /// This is for show snack bar
  final _messangerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  Quiz quiz = Quiz();

  List<Widget> scoreKeeper = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      scaffoldMessengerKey: _messangerKey,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    quiz.getQuestion(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            boolButton(Colors.green, 'True'),
            boolButton(Colors.red, 'False'),
            Row(
              children: scoreKeeper,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded boolButton(Color c, String s) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(c),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            (quiz.q.length - 1) > quiz.counter ? setState(
                  () {
                switcher(s);
                quiz.nextQuestion();
              },
            ) : _messangerKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(duration: Duration(seconds : 2),content: Text('No more questions')));
          },
          child: Text(
            s,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  switcher(String s) {
    if (quiz.getAnswer().toLowerCase() == s.toLowerCase()) {
      scoreKeeper.add(
        const Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      scoreKeeper.add(
        const Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is the `list.dart` file

```
import 'question.dart';

class Quiz {
  int counter = 0;

  final List<Question> q = [
    Question(
      'Cows can only be lead up a flight of stairs and not down.',
      'False',
    ),
    Question(
      'Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.',
      'True',
    ),
    Question(
      'A slug\'s blood is green.',
      'True',
    ),
  ];

  void nextQuestion() {
    counter++;
  }

  String getQuestion() {
    return q[counter].question;
  }

  String getAnswer() {
    return q[counter].answer;
  }
}
```

And this is the `question.dart` file

```
class Question {
  String question;
  String answer;
  Question(this.question, this.answer);
}
```